STM32 not reading temperatures from DS18B20 temperature sensor
I am trying to read temperatures from multiple DS18B20 on a STM32 NUCLEO BOARD. I am currently able to read from a single sensor with the SKIP ROM command, and I am also able to read the sensor identifier with the READ ROM command. When trying to read from a single sensor with MATCH ROM command I am not receiving anything.
My code is the following:
{
    uint8_t TxBuffer[8];
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
      if ((data & (1<<i)) != 0){
          TxBuffer[i] = 0xFF;
      }
      else{
          TxBuffer[i] = 0;
      }
    }
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, TxBuffer, 8, 10);
} 

uint8_t DS18B20_Init(void)
{
    uint8_t ResetByte = 0xF0, PresenceByte;
    //LL_USART_SetBaudRate(huart1.Instance, HAL_RCC_GetPCLK2Freq(), 9600);
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
    HAL_HalfDuplex_Init(&huart1);
    // Send reset pulse (0xF0)
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &ResetByte, 1, 1);
    // Wait for the presence pulse
    HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, &PresenceByte, 1, 1);
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    HAL_HalfDuplex_Init(&huart1);
    // Check presence pulse
    if (PresenceByte != ResetByte){
        return 1; // Presence pulse detected
    }
    else{
        return 0; // No presence pulse detected
    }
}

void DS18B20_SampleTemp(void)
{
    DS18B20_Init();
    DS18B20_WriteByte(0xCC);  // Skip ROM   (ROM-CMD)
    DS18B20_WriteByte(0x44);  // Convert T  (F-CMD)
}

float DS18B20_ReadTemp(void)
{
    uint8_t Temp_LSB, Temp_MSB;
    uint16_t Temp;
    float Temperature;

    DS18B20_SampleTemp();
    DS18B20_Init();
    DS18B20_WriteByte(0xCC);  // Skip ROM         (ROM-CMD)
    DS18B20_WriteByte(0xBE);  // Read Scratchpad  (F-CMD)
    Temp_LSB = DS18B20_ReadByte();
    Temp_MSB = DS18B20_ReadByte();
    Temp = ((Temp_MSB<<8))|Temp_LSB;
    Temperature = (float)Temp/16.0;

    return Temperature;
}

void DS18B20_MatchROM(uint8_t rom[8])
{
    DS18B20_SampleTemp();

    DS18B20_Init();

    DS18B20_WriteByte(0x55); // Match ROM command

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        DS18B20_WriteByte(rom[i]);
    }

    DS18B20_WriteByte(0xBE);  // Read Scratchpad  (F-CMD)

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        romCode[i] = DS18B20_ReadByte();
    }
    print("\n\rResponse: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      printHex(romCode[i]);
    }
}

uint8_t sensorROM1[8] = {0x2B, 0xFF, 0x64, 0x0E, 0x75, 0x37, 0x8B, 0x66};
  while (1)
  {
      DS18B20_MatchROM(sensorROM1);
      HAL_Delay(500);

  }


You miscopied the device ID - first byte should be 0x28, rather than 0x2B.

I have tried it both ways, I think my problem comes in the order or timings I send the commands

You should be checking the return values from all HAL functions that return one.

Where did you get your DS18B20 from? I think it is not the problem about your code, but the question about the DS18B20 chip you have, the genuine DS18B20 has the ROM code as 0x28 with a pattern of 0x28 xx xx xx xx 00 00 xx. Your DS18B20 does not match the ROM code nor the pattern. You might want to test your DS18B20 with this test code to see what it will shown up?

That's true, but I have tried it with some "real" sensors and it does not work either
